# Stronger Whitney approximation for smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, approximation-theory

If $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, then any continuous map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is homotopic to a smooth map $g:M\rightarrow N$. If $f$ is smooth on a closed set $K\subseteq M$, the homotopy can be taken relative to $K$. (This is in proven in e.g. Lee).
Now assume that we have a metric $\rho$ on $N$. I was wondering if, additionally, $g$ can be taken to be a $\delta$-approximation of $f$ where $\delta:M\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a continuous map (i.e. $\rho(f(x),g(x))\leq \delta(x)$ for all $x\in M$).
There is a theorem in *Metric Structures in Differential Geometry* by Walschap (Theorem 1.2) that states something similar, but $N$ is assumed to be compact. Is this necessary?

Comment: If you have acess to Kosinski's differnetial manifolds book, then theorem 2.5 (page 8) is close to what you want.  The only differences are that his $\delta$ is constant, and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Even better:  page 47, again Theorem 2.5 (b)is exactly what you want.

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to post an answer to the question, to get the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out to me, this (almost exact) statement is proven in *Differential Manifolds* by Kosinski (Chapter III, Theorem 2.5).

Comment: I don't think Kosinski's proof is complete - what he actually proves is that if $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$, then we can find a smooth $\delta$-approximation of $f$. If we did not need to worry about the metric on $N$, then Whitney Embedding Theorem would imply that this holds for general manifolds $N$, but I'm not aware of any results about the distance-preserving properties of the Whitney embedding.